# Install python modules not in the local user directory

Tags: python, python3, pip

I am not sure if this SE is the correct place for this question. If not, please let me know.

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 (clean install)  
Python `--version`: 3.8.2  
pip `--version`: `pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`.
```

Now, when I install anything with `pip3`, I get:

```
WARNING: The scripts *some_scripts* are installed in '/home/user_name/.local/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

When I run `jupyter noteboook` (I have installed it) in a terminal inside a folder, I get

```
Command 'jupyter' not found, but can be installed with: ...
```

I am able to run the `jupyter notebook` with `~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook`
Additionally, it seems all the packages like `numpy`, `jupyter-notebook`, `pandas`, etc. have been installed in `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`

I do not want to add the above mentioned paths to the `PATH` variable. Instead, is there a way I could install all of these packages to the directory which is in `PATH`?
The answer to [this question: Pip3 Install Module For All Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54971457/pip3-install-module-for-all-users) just shows a way to add the above mentioned directory to `PATH`. I want to not tinker with `PATH` at all.

As an aside question, now that there is no `python 2.x` installed with `Ubuntu 20.04`, can I change the command `python` to run what used to be `python3` before? It is my understanding that I should add `alias python=python3` to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` files.

Comment: BTW, `echo $PATH` displays:
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`


Pasting this here, just in case it is useful to know.

Comment: It's fascinating that /home/$YOU/bin and /home/$YOU/.local/bin aren't on your $PATH. They should be. You could simply move *some_scripts* to a location that IS on your $PATH, since you have ruled out the other easy option of editing your $PATH.

Comment: I would not add that alias, and would distrust anybody who told me to do so. You can do it (it's your system), and it might not break your 20.04-and-newer system but it may have unintended consequences if you later install Python2 for any reason. On older systems (16.04 and earlier), that alias will break your system.

Comment: What if you `sudo` the `pip3 install` ? And I do not understand why you don't add the .local/bon to your PATH either, unless it is to install for all users